# Are individuals required to report payments to independent contractors (1099) to CA EDD?

Tags: united-states, taxes, california, contractor, form-1099

A friend is issuing 1099-MISC as an individual for payments to an independent contractor over $600 during last year.

Should he also report those payments to CA state?